# error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Animal

Tags: java

```
class Animal
{  
    public void getName(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("Name of Animal : "+name);
    } 
}
class Dog extends Animal
{  
    public void getBreed(String breedName)
    {
        System.out.println("Breed Name : "+breedName);
    } 
}
class Program16
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
        Dog d=new Dog();  
        d.getName("Tommy");
        d.getBreed("Labrador"); 
    }
}
```

**Output**

D:\JavaCollege>javac Program16.java

D:\JavaCollege>java Program16.java

error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: Animal

Comment: Please copy the text of your program/output and paste it in the question with the proper formatting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't see any issues in the code, if you are executing the code in a single file as it was shown in the code above, make sure you make the `class Program16` public, for eg, `public class Program16` the class with the main method should be public to execute the java program.

Answer (score 5):

The code it fine<sup>1</sup> - it's the way you're running it that's the problem.

Instead of this:

```sh
java Program16.java
```

Run this:

```sh
java Program16
```

That tells the `java` command which *class* you want to run. You've already compiled the source files (`.java`) into class files (`.class`) so now you just want the JVM to execute the `main` method in the `Program16` class.

---

<sup>1</sup> The way you're specifying the type of the `args` parameter is unconventional, but valid. It would be more conventional to write it as `String[] args` - the syntax with `[]` at the end of the name was introduced for compatibility with other languages, but is generally regarded as less readable than keeping all the type information together.